# How do I run some code if an Excel table column is filtered and other code if it is not filtered?

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I can run code if the entire table is filtered, but I want to isolate it to certain columns being filtered.

(Code block #1)
I tried this to use the same code I use to clear the filter in a single column. This did not work and I am not surprised, but I am stumped on what to do from here.

(Code block #2)
I also tried setting the column as a range and use the autofilter property, but when the code runs autofilter is disabled for the entire table instead of the filter being cleared for that single column.

```
    If Worksheets("Inventory").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter 
       Field:=10 Then

    'some code


    Else

    'do something else
```

```
dim myRange as Range
Set myRange = Range("Table1[Alert]")

If myRange.autofilter = false then

'some code

Else

'do something else
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to preserve the filtering, or you can remove filtering from your column of interest? In the latter case, you can get the number of visible cells using `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`,  compare the number of cells before and after removing the filter from column 10, and run the code based on comparison. The problem is I can't find a way to restore the filter criteria after they've been removed, unless they were initially set with VBA.

Comment: That is a good idea, but there is still the problem you referenced in your comment.

Comment: Actually I might have an idea which will work for simple criteria. Get the visible range of column 10, copy it to new sheet, remove duplicates and the resulting values are your filter criteria. This, of course, does not apply to criteria like ">10"

Comment: This is a decent workaround for now. Thanks for your ideas :)